# Can a CAM-style abstract machine fold a tree? What if it has a second stack?

Tags: computation-models, ocaml

The title's a little provocative, sorry. In the [categorical abstract machines (CAMs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_abstract_machine), technically there are no "right folds"; the only way to consume a list is from the "left" or "top" of the list. Less abstractly, a list like `[1;2;3]` (OCaml) or `(list 1 2 3)` (Scheme) can only be consumed by a CAM on a cons-by-cons basis, starting with 1, followed by 2, and ending at 3. Technically, the actual ending is a nil value.

Nonetheless a right fold can be implemented from a left fold, because list reversal can be encoded as a left fold. So, to right-fold a list on a CAM, use two left folds; the first fold reverses the list, and the second fold traverses the list in the desired order.

Another way to implement a right fold is to use a secondary stack, in the tradition of Forth. Pushing a list from the register to the secondary stack, cons by cons, will effectively reverse it; to make an iterator, just push an end-of-iteration token to the secondary stack first.

Neither of these approaches seem to be sufficient for folding binary trees. Consider a datatype like:

```
type 'a tree = Leaf | Branch of ('a * 'a tree * 'a tree)
```

It's not clear how to right-fold such a type. If we imagine using a secondary stack to pull apart a tree, then we run into ordering issues, and have to pick/roll the stack to get our intermediate values. Before I put more effort into finding a solution which uses both stacks, I just want to know: **can a CAM even express this sort of fold? Is the second stack necessary?**

(I know that CAMs are usually implemented with extra bells and whistles for general recursion, but I'll prefer answers which preserve the CAM abstraction, because my implementation JIT-compiles CAM instructions and flat bytecode is faster than recursion.)